# Memory Leak in QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a window with a QWebEngineView, and delete the QWebEngineView after the window closes. However, the QWebEngineView never seems to get deleted, and keeps running any QUrl I have loaded (e.g. a YouTube video). In my program, I have a QMainWindow with a Line Edit and a Push Button, that creates a window that loads the URL entered by the user. Here is my code:

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "subwindow.h"


namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void init();
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    SubWindow *sub;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**SubWindow.h**

```
#ifndef SUBWINDOW_H
#define SUBWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/qwebengineview.h>
#include <QTimer>

namespace Ui
{
class SubWindow;
}

class SubWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SubWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void doWeb(QString link);
    ~SubWindow();

private:
    Ui::SubWindow *ui;
    QWebEngineView *web;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

};

#endif // SUBWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void MainWindow::init()
{
    this->showMaximized();

    sub = new SubWindow(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    sub->doWeb(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

**SubWindow.cpp**

```
#include "subwindow.h"
#include "ui_subwindow.h"

SubWindow::SubWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SubWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void SubWindow::doWeb(QString link)
{
    this->show();
    web = new QWebEngineView(this);

    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(web);

    web->load(QUrl(link, QUrl::TolerantMode));
    web->show();
}

SubWindow::~SubWindow()
{
    delete web; //Doesn't seem to work, since memory is still allocated in task manager
    delete ui;
}

void SubWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    this->close(); //Artifact for testing purposes.
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.init();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have also tried using "web->close();" (which I put on the line where I have the testing artifact) in conjunction with
"web->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);" (which I put after "web = new QWebEngineView(this);"), but that didn't solve my issue either. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know that the QWebEngine not destroyed?

Comment: For one, I use the task manager, and notice that before I press the MainWindow Push Button, the program uses about 55MB of RAM. After I press it, it goes to about 144MB, which still remains allocated after closing the SubWindow. Other than that, when I load a YouTube video, I can still hear the sound playing after closing the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating QWebEngineView with parent "this" (owner) so you don't have to delete it yourself, it will be automatically deleted when it parent will. See Qt documentation about memory management :

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

it is also dangerous doing that, because if you don't create the QWebEngineView object using doWeb(QString link), you will try to delete something that doesn't exist and therefore it can lead you to undefined behavior.

remove `delete web` from your destructor and see if you always have the problem.

**Edit :**
The reason why it is not destroyed : you aren't destroying SubWindow Object (the owner of QWebEngineView Object). You can Verify it yourself by printing something in the destructor.
If you were destroying SubWindow object, the second time you push the button in MainWindow, your application will crashes. Since you aren't creating the SubWindow object inside your function on_push_button, but inside MainWindow::init. Your SubWindow Object is only hidden and not destroyed. It is destroyed only when you close the MainWindow. You are also Creating an instance of QWebEngineview each time you show sub (SubWindow Object), so if you show sub 3 times you will have 3 QWebEngineView inside your Subwindow.

the changes i would do to the code :

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "subwindow.h"

namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    SubWindow* sub;
};
#endif
```

**mainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow), sub(new SubWindow(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    sub->show();
    sub->doWeb(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

**subWindow.h**

```
#ifndef SUBWINDOW_H
#define SUBWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/qwebengineview.h>
#include <QTimer>

namespace Ui
{
class SubWindow;
}

class SubWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SubWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void doWeb(QString link);
    ~SubWindow();

private:
    Ui::SubWindow *ui;
    QWebEngineView *web;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

};

#endif // SUBWINDOW_H
```

**subWindow.cpp**

```
#include "subwindow.h"
#include "ui_subwindow.h"

SubWindow::SubWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SubWindow),
    web(new QWebEngineView(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(web);
}
void SubWindow::doWeb(QString link)
{
    web->load(QUrl(link, QUrl::TolerantMode));
}
SubWindow::~SubWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void SubWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    this->close(); //Artifact for testing purposes.
}
```

Note that i am also not destroying subWindow object, but i m not creating QWebView each time i call the method SubWindow::doWeb(String).
If it was up to me i would use a Subclassed Dialog that is not a member of MainWindow, the object would be created inside MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() and destroyed when i finish using it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am aware that using "this" makes an object get deleted before its parent, however, seeing that my WebEngineView was never deleted, I added "delete web" in my destructor to see if it would work. Obviously, this failed, so I tried "web->deleteLater();", which surprisingly worked. I still don't understand why this is the case though.

Comment: i found the reason why it is leaking. I Edited my answer.

Comment: Your code does't exactly work, since SubWindow never gets access to the requested website, due to the fact that you never create a QWebView. However, If I just add "this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);" in SubWindow's constructor, without making any changes to my original code, the leak is gone, thus proving your point of me never destroying my SubWindow. Wow, I feel dumb! As for the crash you mentioned, I solved it by moving "sub = new SubWindow(this);" in the "void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()", just before calling doWeb(). Thank you! You were most helpful!

Comment: i created the QWebViewEngine inside the SubWindow Constructor. the code works i tested it.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice you actually created it. It is quite strange that when I use it, the button doesn't respond to me clicking it though. Anyway, thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

OK, apparently I needed to call "web->deleteLater();" before calling 
"this->close();". The "delete web;" was uneeded. Still, I'd like to know why delete doesn't work in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something was not closed correctly.

I was using Qt 5.15 using the kit MSVC2019 32bit compiler. But Visual Studio 2017 (and not 2019) was installed on my computer. Thus, the compiler detected in Qt creator -> project -> manage kit -> compiler was the one of MSVC2017 i.e : Microsoft visual C++ compiler 15.8 (x86).

The solution is to install visual Studio 2019 and then replace Qt creator by the correct compiler (2019) i.e: Microsoft visual c++ compiler 16.7 (X86).
Then I could compile without any leak of memory anymore.

[image: Problem_With_QTWebEngine_And_MSVC_Compiler 15.8]